# Name or service not known when try to send email with flask-mail

Tags: python, flask, flask-mail

Hello I have the following configuration in the thunderbird:

[image]

And I set this configuration inside app with:

```
app.config["MAIL_SERVER"] = "smtp....."
app.config["MAIL_PORT"] = 587
app.config["MAIL_USERNAME"] = "info@...."
app.config["MAIL_PASSWORD"] = "pasword"
app.config["MAIL_USE_TLS"] = True
app.config["MAIL_USE_SSL"] = False
```

but when I try to send an email with

```
from flask_mail import Message, Mail

mail = Mail(app)

msg = Message(
    "Hello", sender="info@....", recipients=["tlaloc@es.es"]
)
try:
    mail.send(msg)
except Exception as e:
    print("---------")
    print(e)
```

I got the following error:

```
[Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

how can I solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The app.config["MAIL_SERVER"] configuration was wrong.